# SharePoint REST api call within office add-in

Tags: sharepoint-online, outlook, add-ins, outlook-add-in

I need to get all the sites a user has access to within an O365 tenant. I can use the SharePoint REST api. But how can I authenticate the user using a token?

Can someone provide a good guide to call SharePoint REST API as current user.

Comment: Hey mate, did you found the solution?